# C string size on stack from different c string array

Tags: c, string, embedded, microcontroller

I want to debug my microcontroller program in C by sending strings via UART.
Now I'm facing a problem joining debug strings together, as I have to work with c strings.
I need to have `debugMessageOnStack` on the stack.

Consider following example:
I need a string like "My favorite color is mountbatten pink"

```
const char debugMessageStart[] = "My favorite color is ";
const char* colors[MAX_COLORS] = {[GREEN] = "green", [ORANGE] = "orange", [PINK] = "mountbatten pink"};

char debugMessageOnStack[DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
```

I know it is pretty easy to calculate `DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH` by hand, but i want it to be calculated dynamically, so I don't have to recalculate it by hand everytime I add a new color string that's longer than all existing color strings.

Theoretically it should be possible as every string length in `colors` is known before compiling, but I don't know how I can do it.

Thanks!

Comment: The easy way: if you're not really short of stack space you should just declare `char debugMessageOnStack[DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH];` with `DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH]` being longer than any message, e.g 300, which should be more than enough.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Allocating 300 bytes on the stack is a no-go in most microcontroller systems, even high-end ones. If you need that much, you'd allocate it as a `static` in `.bss` instead.

Comment: I added the embedded tag now. A microcontroller is a form of embedded system CPU with built-in hardware peripherals. It is not a very small guy working with finance and it is not a PC. Thus answers need to be suitable for microcontroller embedded systems.

Comment: A better solution may be to not try to assemble the whole string in memory but simply output it to the serial output stream incrementally.  If your serial I/O is buffered then you will effectively be using the existing buffer to assemble the string.

Comment: @Clifford In case it is using DMA then there might be a need to write everything down at once, in advance (in the DMA buffer).

Comment: @Lundin Yes - it might - hence the equivocation.  But even then you could (and should IMO) feed the DMA buffer from a ring buffer or byte queue.  Just another layer of abstraction - the underlying hardware mechanisms are best hidden from the application layer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, "but i want it to be calculated dynamically" doesn't make much sense since your array must be large enough to handle the worst case scenario. Your code can't run off into the woods with stack overflow during the worst case scenario, so you could simply allocate the array large enough for that one.

It doesn't make sense to "save some stack space" when not under the worst case scenario, since this is just a local variable anyhow and will get deallocated after use no matter size.

---

Instead of an array of strings, use an array of structs:

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t length;
  const char* str;
} color_t;

const color_t colors[] =
{
  [GREEN] = { sizeof("green")-1, "green" },
  ...
};
```

That way everything is stored in flash and computed at compile-time. If you are pedantic about reducing code repetition, then you could add a mysterious macro (generally not recommended):

```
#define COLOR_INIT(str) { sizeof(str)-1, str }
...
[GREEN] = COLOR_INIT("green"),
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally one should avoid using a variable sized object on stack. First, there is a risk that the size of string can grow too much to be kept on stack. The second, stack allocation with **automatic** VLAs or `alloca()` is usually less efficient than for a fixed size object (though still faster than `malloc()`).

Anyway, to deal with a unknown size string on the stack you could use `snprintf` function. The function works like `printf()` but it stores the characters to a string. However, if one passes **`NULL`** as a buffer and 0 as size it returns a number of characters that would be stored to  a buffer.

The string would be produced in two passes:

```c
size_t n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "My favorite color is %s", colors[ORANGE]);
char msg[n + 1]; // 1 for the terminator
snprintf(msg, n + 1, "My favorite color is %s", colors[ORANGE]);
```

It may be a good idea to wrap the message generation into a helper to avoid
repeating:

```c
size_t mk_msg(char *msg, size_t n, int color) {
  return snprintf(msg, n, "My favorite color is %s", colors[color]);
}
```

The advantage of this methodology is that it is very generic and reusable.

Comment: `stdio.h` functions is typically to be avoided in embedded systems, since they are inefficient and takes lots of memory. Plus the usual problems with these functions having a horrible, bug-prone and dangerous API. There's no need to execute this in run-time at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports VLAs the you can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_COLORS 3
#define GREEN 0
#define ORANGE 1
#define PINK 2

const char debugMessageStart[] = "My favorite color is ";
const char* colors[] = { [GREEN] = "green",[ORANGE] = "orange", [PINK] = "mountbatten pink" };

int main(void) 
{
  const char* color = colors[ORANGE];
  int length = strlen(debugMessageStart) + strlen(color) + 1;
  char debugMessageOnStack[length];
  strcpy(debugMessageOnStack, debugMessageStart);
  strcat(debugMessageOnStack, color);
  printf("%s\n", debugMessageOnStack);
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient though. This is for an embedded system, real-time performance is usually the most valuable resource.

Comment: @Lundin: Engineer's time is almost always much more expensive than a few cycles.

Comment: @TomV Except if you don't know how to allocate a bunch of simple look-up tables in flash memory, you are probably not a (software) engineer... In this case it's building an output buffer to an UART, so the code likely needs to be executed in a timely fashion, ideally longer than the time it takes to send a byte with the given baudrate.